# Woo Commerce adds product 3 in cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

The website https://www.tradetoolsni.co.uk/ when you add a single item to the cart it goes in 3 times instead of once see the cart here https://www.tradetoolsni.co.uk/cart/?add-to-cart=495

Comment: please post your add-to-cart function

Comment: Clear your web browser's cache, or hard refresh - for windows ctrl + f5 , for mac command + R, everything working perfectly over here.